# Role based access control django like AWS IAM

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, rbac

Recntly I am working on a project where I need to apply **role based access control(RBAC)** something like **AWS IAM**. Django already have Groups & permission. I can create a group & add user on that group. Then the user on that group can access to resource. But I've got a problem on that solution. In AWS IAM user can log in to the same account not a different account. How can I implement same feature like aws. I don't want to use account id like aws, user can login with their email/phone & password. Some of my models I use a field **created_by** with a relation with **user**. On my views, my queryset something like this `MyModel.objects.filter(created_by=request.user)`. The problem is suppose I give **user1** permission to access **MyModel**. **user1** doesn't have any objects created by himself. He need to view the objects that created by the **root user**. There is also another problem is that the root user isn't belong to any group.

I tried using group & permission which provided by django. I also customize the django **Group** model add a field **created_by** to track the group owner. But what if the **user1** create a group and the group owner will be **user1**, there I've lost my track to the **root user**. I don't need to implement **object level permission** but in future it may be needed. One more thing I've to check each time current user can be able to perform this action or not. Is it will be best if I check it on the view or I make a custom middleware where I can check the user permission?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't need to implement object level permission but in future it may be needed.

Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relationship-based_access_control. This gives you fine-grained permissions. There are multiple solutions available that you can use, both open source and non-open source.

> Will it be best if I check it on the view or I make a custom middleware where I can check the user permission?

The backend (e.g. a middleware) should always check for the right permissions before accessing a resource.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've already implemented a solution. Tracking non root user account by root user account_id something like AWS IAM. Create a custom middleware to get the root user and added it on request, and checking permission on view level.